# IE 7 and IE 8 fix on multiple background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Good day!

I am currently trying to create a background-image with multiple images on it.
My code is as follows:

```
background-image: url("/test/images/texture-diagonals.png"),     url("/test/images/texture-dark2.gif");
```

But it doesn't work in IE7 and IE8.

I've read the following solution in [this website](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1309)
But what does it mean that i need to position it relative to html?

Or are there other ways to fix this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple backgrounds are not supported in IE7/8.